# How to Disable CSS of one of two col-md-12 divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made 2 Divisions out of bootstrap property `<div class="col-md-12" >` on the same page. In the first one, I have added a different Background and some hover property, now in the second one I have to make a "Sign Up" Div but with other properties with the same `<div class="col-md-12" >` ie. Full page width row. But the changes are happening on both the Divisions.

Can somebody Help ?

I am using Visual Studio 13 for `aspx` webpage.

Sorry if it is a silly question.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: if both divs have same parent then us parent div :nth-child(1) and parent div:nth-child(2)

Comment: Give a different class to the first one, e.g. `<div class="col-md-12 background" >`

Comment: If you are modifying the `col-md-12` class the changes will be applied to all elements with that class, best is to add a second class to the division and add the styles to that class instead of the `col-md-12` class

Answer (score 1):

You can append another class to the ones you want to style:

```
<div class="col-md-12 styleme">
    Content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.styleme {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

This way, you can style the div using your own custom class as opposed to overriding BootStrap's native one.

NOTE: ensure to place the custom style in your own custom CSS file and ensure it is referenced in your site AFTER the BootStrap CSS file.